# Can I pass functions as parameter and the function can hold different arguments?

Tags: c

Currently I call function in this way:

```
typedef struct OptionValueStruct{  
    const char *option_name;    
    int (*func)(char*, char**);    
} OptionValueStruct_t;  


int parse2parameter(char *opt_name, char** opt_val);  
int parse3parameter(char *opt_name, char** opt_val, int a);


const OptionValueStruct_t option_values[] = {  
{"Counter1", parse2parameter}  
};
```

where parse2parameter is a func() having 2 parameters which is defined in OptionValueStruct_t.
How is it possible I use

```
const OptionValueStruct_t option_values[] = {  
{"Counter1", parse2parameter},  
{"Counter2", parse3parameter}  
};
```

Where parse2parameter() and parse3parameter() has different number/type of parameters?

Comment: Put all that into a codebox. You can do that by selecting all that code (remove the "`" first), and clicking on the 101010 button in the rich text editor. Alternatively, you can add some spacing between the code and other text, and indent the code with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

What are you really trying to do, and why?

Think about the code where you receive the function pointer. How are you going to know how to call it?

Comment: because different counters require different functions. Thx

Comment: I don't think you understand what I asked. "How" is not answered with "because".

Comment: An answer for how to know how to call it is in my answer (add some value(s) to the structure which indicate the function type).

Answer (score 0):

Look at `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`.  You will not be limited by two and three arguments.

Comment: seems this applys when we have severl functions with the same name but differnt number/type of parameters. but my fucntion name is also different. so if using va_start, I need to create a function which wrap parse2parameter() and parse3parameter

Comment: @user389955: it applies when you have a `printf` like function.  It can print any number of variables you pass to it because it uses these `va_arg`, `va_start` and `va_end`.  The first parameter being a string constant that `printf` parses in order to learn about how many follow and their types, and prints them.  The first two parameters in your functions appear to have same type.  So if you add a string constant as a third parameter and parse it, you will be able to do all the work using simply one function.  If you have reasons to not use this, showing the code will be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `int(*)()`, and have some other parameter(s) that describe the function signature so that you can call it.  For example:

```
typedef struct OptionValueStruct{
    const char *option_name;
    int (*func)(); /* actually takes some arguments */
    unsigned num_args; /* might need more fields to describe the args */
} OptionValueStruct_t;
```

...

```
switch (value.num_args){
case 2: ((int (*)(char*, char**))value.func)(opt_name, opt_val);
case 3: ((int (*)(char*, char**, int))value.func)(opt_name, opt_val, a);
}
```

Another way would be to just declare the pointer func to match `parse3parameter`, and then always call it as if it took three arguments, and (on some platforms), the third argument will simply be ignored.  This is probably not portable though.

Comment: No.  You cannot convert a function pointer to a `void*`, since it is not guaranteed that `sizeof(function pointer) <= sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: Can you name a platform where that non-guarantee is broken?  Anyway, if you want to be very precise about the whole thing, I guess you can just write the type as pointer-to-void-function and be done with it, as a pointer to one function in C is the same size as a pointer to any other function.  I'll update my answer to do that.